# How to use the same form for creating and editing in ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am new to ruby. I have the same form but i need it to perform creation/updation as and when required. The problem i have now is that whenever i call edit instead of editing the details of an existing user, i am getting a new user with the edited details. To put it simply, i think whenever i perform edit, the create method is being called.

So is there any way to use single form for both new and edit instead of using separate forms.

**The following code is for editing user details:**

```
         <%= link_to 'Home', root_path %>
        <h2>Edit user</h2>
        <%= form_for :user, url: user_index_path do |f| %>
          <p>
            <%= f.label :name %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :name %>
          </p>

          <p>
            <%= f.label :address %><br>
            <%= f.text_area :address %>
          </p>
         <p>
            <%= f.label :email %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :email %>
          </p> 
         <p>
            <%= f.label :phone %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :phone %>
          </p>
          <p>
            <%= f.label :state %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :state %>
          </p>
          <p>
            <%= f.label :country %> 
            <%= f.collection_select(:country, Country.all, :name, :name) %>
          </p>
          <p>
            <%= f.submit %>
          </p>
        <% end %>
```

**The following code is for creating user:**

```
        <%= link_to 'Home', root_path %>
    <h2>Create new user</h2>
    <%= form_for :user, url: user_index_path do |f| %>
      <p>
        <%= f.label :name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </p>

      <p>
        <%= f.label :address %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :address %>
      </p>
     <p>
        <%= f.label :email %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
      </p> 
     <p>
        <%= f.label :phone %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :phone %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= f.label :state %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :state %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= f.label :country %> 
        <%= f.collection_select(:country, Country.all, :name, :name) %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
```

**And this is my controller:**

```
      class UserController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @users = User.all

    end

    def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

    def new
        @user = User.new
    end


    def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save
            redirect_to @user
        else
            render 'new'
        end 
    end

  def edit

    @user = User.find(params[:id])


  end

    def update
    #@user = User.find(params[:id])
        if @user.update(user_params)
        redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
    end

    def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
      redirect_to user_index_path
  end

    private
    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :address, :email, :phone, :state, :country)
    end

end
```

Since i am new to ruby, i did not get the exact details of how http requests function in ruby.

Comment: You need to change `<%= form_for :user, url: user_index_path do |f| %>` to `<%= form_for @user, url: user_index_path do |f| %>`

Comment: Now i am getting an error. "No route matches [PATCH] "/user""

Comment: Please paste your `routes`

Comment: You need to uncomment this line in your update action `@user = User.find(params[:id])`

Comment: method index with action post will always call create method of a controller, so make the changes what I have done in my answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

users/_form.html.erb

```
  <%= link_to 'Home', root_path %>
  <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <p>
  <%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
  <%= f.label :address %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :address %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= f.label :email %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p> 
  <p>
  <%= f.label :phone %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= f.label :state %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :state %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= f.label :country %> 
  <%= f.collection_select(:country, Country.all, :name, :name) %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
  <% end %>
```

users/new.html.erb

```
<h2>Create new user</h2>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

users/edit.html.erb

```
<h2>Edit user</h2>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show    
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end 
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to user_index_path
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :address, :email, :phone, :state, :country)
  end

  def find_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

When you have same view code for two or more methods, you should create a partial of same view code and render it in those methods. This is called **DRY** principle in ruby on rails

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about it. I'll make sure that i wont repeat codes in future. But i still need a solution for my problem.

Comment: what is your problem now?

Comment: whenever i perform 'edit' a new entry is created instead of editing the existing one

Comment: Should i paste the entire log??

Comment: Started GET "/user/40/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-01 10:53:49 +0530
Processing by UserController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"40"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 40 LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mCountry Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT `countries`.* FROM `countries`
  Rendered user/_form.html.erb (6.2ms)
  Rendered user/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (7.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 36ms (Views: 34.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79287/discussion-between-akshay-and-user123).